# how to delete all users and posts based on 'user_meta'?

Tags: custom-post-types, users, post-meta, user-meta

I have developed a small wordpress application where It has Institutes(wp user), Trainers(wp user), Trainees(wp user), courses(custom post) and notifications(custom post). All the application is working fine but If I delete an institute all the information belongs to that institute like Trainers, Trainee, notifications & courses should also be deleted. While I was creating the 'institute' user I am storing the all the related info like first name, last name in wordpress table 'wp_users' and 'institute name' is storing as 'user meta' with key 'inistitute_name' in 'wp_usermeta' table like below is my code:

```
  $user_data = array(
            'ID' => '',
            'user_pass' => '',
            'user_login' => $first_name,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'role' => 'admin'//get_option('default_option')
        );
        $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_name',$insititute_name );
```

While creating Trainer (or) Trainee my code is like below:

```
  $user_data = array(
               'ID' => '',
               'user_pass' => '',
               'user_login' => $first_name,
               'user_email' => $trainer_email,
               'first_name' => $first_name,
               'last_name' => $last_name,
               'role' => 'trainer'
         ); 
        $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_name',$this->institute_name[0] );
        wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

While creating courses my code is like below:

```
  $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
  $institute_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'inistitute_name', true);
  $post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $description,
            'post_status'   => 'publish', 
            'post_type' => "courses"  
        );
  $id = wp_insert_post($post);
  update_post_meta( $id, 'inistitute_name', $institute_name );
```

Suppose let us say if a institute 'abcd' is deleted then all the information like 'trainer', 'trainee', 'courses' & 'notifications' associated with that institute should also be deleted based on a 'user_meta' field. Is it possible to delete? (or) did I do any mistake? can anyone tell me what was I doing wrong?

Update:

```
  add_action( 'delete_user', 'cyb_delete_institute_info' );
function cyb_delete_institute_info( $id ) {

$user = get_userdata( $id );

if( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( "admin", (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    // Deleted user is admin, check `institute_name` meta field
    $institute_name = get_user_meta( $id, 'inistitute_name', true );

    if( ! empty( $institute_name ) ) {
        // Deleted user is an admin and has `institute_name` meta,
        // so, it is a "Institute" user

        // Get posts to delete
        $posts_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'notifications',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key'   => 'inistitute_name',
                'value' => $institute_name
            ),
        );

global $wpdb;
$querystr = "DELETE FROM $wpdb->wp_dxwe_posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->wp_dxwe_postmeta ON $wpdb->wp_dxwe_postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID WHERE $wpdb->wp_dxwe_postmeta.meta_key = 'inistitute_name' AND 
        $wpdb->wp_dxwe_postmeta.meta_value = '$institute_name' AND $wpdb->wp_dxwe_posts.post_type = 'courses' ";
$wpdb->query( $querystr );

        $posts_args2 = array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key'   => 'inistitute_name',
                'value' => $institute_name
            ),
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $posts_args );
        $query2 = new WP_Query( $posts_args2 );
        $posts_to_delete = $query->get_posts();
        $posts_to_delete2 = $query2->get_posts();

        foreach( $posts_to_delete as $post ) {
            wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
        }

        foreach( $posts_to_delete2 as $post ) {
            wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
        }

        // Get users to delete
        $users_args = array(
            'role__in'       => array( 'trainer', 'trainee' ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key'   => 'inistitute_name',
                'value' => $institute_name
            ),
        );
        $query = new WP_User_Query( $users_args );
        $users_to_delete = $query->get_results();

        foreach( $users_to_delete as $user ) {
            wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
        }

    }

}
}
```

I was writing 2 separate WP_Query's to delete custom post_type's separately but din't work either. same result only notifications deleting correctly but for courses other institute courses also getting deleted.

Comment: Is "institute" a user role?

Comment: @cybmeta, No 'institute' is not a user role but for all institutes who were created will have a user role 'admin' as shown above in my code.

Comment: So, what is the difference between user types "Institute", "trainers", and so on. In posts you work with post types, in users what do you use if not roles? How do you identify a "Institute" user type?

Comment: The difference b/w 'Institute' & 'trainers' is that 'Institute' user will have a role 'admin' where as 'trainer' will have a user role 'trainer'.

Comment: And the difference between Institute and other admins is the `institute_name` meta field? I think you should assign "institute" a user role as well, but that is another question; working on an answer.

Comment: @cybmeta, no there are no other admin's 'Institute' itself is an admin remaining all are 'trainers'(role='trainer') or 'trainees'(role='trainee') like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50183/discussion-between-prasad-chinthala-and-cybmeta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "institute" is a user and you want to perform some actions when it is deleted, you could use [`delete_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_user/) action (as we need information of the deleted user, `deleted_user` may not work, not sure about this but `delete_user` should work for sure). In that hook you can get all users and posts based on `inistitute_name` meta field and delete them.

Seeing your code, "Institute" user type can be identified by user role (you assing `admin`) and user meta `inistitute_name`. So, in `delete_user` action you can check if the deleted user is and admin and if it has `institute_name` assigned, in that case, the deleted user is a "institute" and you can get all other associated users and posts.

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'cyb_delete_institute_info' );
function cyb_delete_institute_info( $id ) {

    $user = get_userdata( $id );

    if( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( "admin", (array) $user->roles ) ) {

        // Deleted user is admin, check `inistitute_name` meta field
        $institute_name = get_user_meta( $id, 'inistitute_name', true );

        if( ! empty( $institute_name ) ) {
            // Deleted user is an admin and has `institute_name` meta,
            // so, it is a "Institute" user

            // Get posts to delete
            $posts_args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'courses', 'notifications' )
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'   => 'inistitute_name',
                    'value' => $institute_name
                ),
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $posts_args );
            $posts_to_delete = $query->get_posts();

            foreach( $posts_to_delete as $post ) {
                wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
            }


            // Get users to delete
            $users_args = array(
                'role__in'       => array( 'trainer', 'trainee' ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'key'   => 'inistitute_name',
                    'value' => $institute_name
                ),
            );
            $query = new WP_User_Query( $users_args );
            $users_to_delete = $query->get_results();

            foreach( $users_to_delete as $user ) {
                wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Note: not tested, just written here as sample code.

Comment: I am trying your solution, testing the application now it will take time since as this is total application level testing.

Comment: I tried& tested your solution by deleting an institute, result is that all 'trainers', 'trainee' & 'notifications' deleted perfectly but 'courses' are deleting more i.e. not only beloved 'institute' courses but also other 'institute' courses getting deleted. can u plz once again check ur answer.

Comment: may be 'compare' field for 'meta_query' is missing in '$posts_args' array that is why it is deleting all other institute courses.

Comment: It is not missing, default value for `compare` argument is `=`, so the code should work for `courses` just like it works for the other custom post types. Can you try to make some debug and check the value of `inistitute_name` filed for the `courses` being deleted?

Comment: I did debug on 'inistitute_name' field for the courses being deleted & before deleting also. it is correct as I gave my institute name. Also checked for other institute courses they have their different insitute_name which they belongs to. Everything looking fine, I don't know whats going wrong!

Comment: In that case, a deeper debug is needed and it is out of what I can do here. In the answer, the same `WP_Query` is used to get `courses` and `notifications`, can you try to do a separate query for each one?

Comment: I tried deleting posts separately but same result problem with the courses persists. plz check my updated question above, see if any mistakes are there.

Comment: I can not see anything wrong in that code and, with the given information, I can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I also have the same thought that there is no mistake. got an idea how about writing 'DELETE' query manually with $wpdb for only 'courses' post type. Please check my updated question and tell me if I wrote query wrongly.

Comment: I got the issue fixed by writing DELETE query manually for both custom post types 'courses' & 'notifications'. much appreciated ur efforts. with few modifications to ur answer I would vote for you.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think direct queries is a good option because you bypass several WordPress hooks and operations. For example, the manual query you have proposed does not delete all database entries for a post (revisions and so on), all related meta data and all related taxonomies relationships; and if some plugin need to do operations on delete post action, it will fail as well. Sorry but the answer for me is not a manual query, so I don't accept the edit. Remember that you can post your own answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: hmmm I understood, but what should I do then as the built-in methods not working fine. anyway, could u plz tell me are there any problems that I may get in the future with these manual query? should I use it or not?